# remove hex value from string

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex

How do I remove the hex value from a string in Python 2.7? Here is the string,

```
\xffDSI\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04\xb3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x06\x00\x06"\x00\x00\x00\x00c\x01,\x00\x00\x06&\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01,\x00\x00\x06\'\x00\x00\x11\x98\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0011_w\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01,\x00\x00\x17\xbf\x00\x00\x11\x98\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00

#b4
,sudd5ly1
!
toddl]
0
able
to
use
a
comput]
to
play
games4
\x00$\x00\x00\x018\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x19\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00\x1d\x00\x1f\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\x08\x00\t\x00'],
['\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\r\x00\x1b\x00\x0e\x00\x0f\x00\x10\x00\x13\x00\x11\x00\x14\x00\x1c\x00\x18\x00
```

I want to display only #b4 to games4. All the hex values should be removed. Thank you.

What I am trying to do is to read in the file type *.dxb, which display braille font. I was able to read the file but the output showed me all those \xffDSI\x00... and then #b4 ,sudd5ly1

The #b4 ,sudd5ly1 is only the part that I want the output to show so that I can do a comparison with other file.

Thank you again.

Comment: Those aren't just hex values. For example, the first line contains the non-hex characters `DSI`.

Comment: just edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
import string
s = '\xffDSI....'
cleaned = ''.join(c for c in s if c in string.printable)
```

This uses `printable` as the definition of "not a hex value", though it does include `\x0b` and `\x0c` (both printable whitespace characters).

Comment: it doesn't work for the string 'test \x0b'